# 8x8 multiplier code and testbench not working(shift-add verilog)

Tags: verilog

I am very new to verilog and am trying to make an 8x8 bit multiplier using the shift-add method.  I can't seem to get my code to work and I'm not sure if it's a syntax problem or just a logical error.  I also attached the testbench file as I'm not sure I'm doing that 100% correctly.  When I run the simulation it says all the inputs and outputs are z. UPDATE: I've added the instance to the testbench but I'm still getting z outputs and inputs.

```
 `timescale 1ns / 1ps
  module lab6code(
    input [7:0] mp, mc,
    input start,
    output reg done,
    reg state,
    reg i, // i is the variable that gets used to check a specific bit in the mplier
    reg [15:0] x, //holder
    output reg [15:0] product,
    input clk);


initial
 begin
    state=0;
    i=0;
    x=0;
 end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    case(state)
    0:
    begin
        if(start==1)
            begin
            x[15:0] <= 4'b0000;
            x[7:0] <= mc; //assign multiplicand to holder
            state <= 1;
            end
    end

    1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15:
    begin
        if(x[i]==0) //checks specific place within mplier array, shifts and moves ahead 2 states
            begin
             x = x << 1; //shifts mcand holder
             state <= state+2; //moves ahead 2 states
             i <= i + 1; //updates i so in the next case the next bit in mplier will be looked at
            end
        else //adds mplier and mcand, moves ahead one state
            begin
             x[7:0] <= x + mp; //adds mplier to the mplier register
             i <= i + 1; //updates i
            end

    end

    2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16: //shifts mcand and goes to next state
    begin
        x = x << 1; //shifts mcand holder
        state <= state + 1; // moves ahead one state
    end

    17:
        begin
        state <=0;
        done = 1;
        end
       endcase
product = x;

end   


endmodule
```

Testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module lab6tb(
output product,
reg start    );

reg mp, mc;

lab6code lab6code_instance(
.mc(mc),
.mp(mp),
.product(product),
.start(start)
);


initial
begin 
start = 1;
mp = 7'b00001011;
mc = 7'b00001001;
end
endmodule
```

Comment: Okay I ran the simulation again and it said mc, mp, start, and CLK are z which means high impedance so I think there is a problem with my testbench file.

Comment: how do know that the values are 'z'? verilog initializes all variables to 'x',  not 'z'. So, you should have seen 'x' instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are not driving all the inputs to your lab6code module, most importantly you are not driving the clock.
The clk signal is left open, so it will be x and none of your events based on its rising edge will happen.
In your test bench, you would need to create a small infinite loop, which would toggle that clock and bring some life in your module.

Something like:

```
reg clk;

initial
  clk = 1'b0;

always
begin
  #10
  clk = ~clk;
end
```

Where #10 is half your clock period.